# Can one assess muscle strength through imaging (e.g., MRI)? If so, though which type of imaging and how accurate is it?

Tags: human-biology, muscles, imaging

Can one assess muscle strength through imaging (e.g., MRI)? If so, though which type of imaging and how accurate is it?

On [How does muscle size relate to strength?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/5706/3806), I read this answer from  [Moses](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/users/1803/moses) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20190508213808/https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/5704/how-does-muscle-size-relate-to-strength)):

> Strength training will increase the size and quantity of myofibrils, and subsequently increase the size of the respective muscle fibers; this process is called hypertrophy, and it results in larger and stronger muscles.

As a result, I assume that a medical imaging processing the physical strength of a muscle should assess both the size and quantity of myofibrils. That being said, it can be easier to assess the size as an approximation of strength, and if so, I wonder about 1) the quality of such an approximation 2) how to measure the size of a muscle that what cannot directly easily measured with a tape ( e.g., gluteus minimus or piriformis).

---

Direct measurement of muscle strength something isn't possible or advised, e.g. if the tendon is injured. Also, some muscles are difficult to isolate when testing. In the case of a tendon injury, assessing the muscle strength would be useful to find a good balance between muscle strengthening and tendon recovery.

Comment: Can you please add some details on what parameters would you consider for "strength"? Different imaging techniques can measure different parameters.

Comment: @WYSIWYG Thanks, I am interested in any parameter that has an effect on the muscle's [physical strength](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_strength).

Comment: To the close voters: this isn't a homework, and please let me know if the edit I made satisfy the "attempt at an answer" requirement.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt The answer linked from Fitness.SE as well as the second answer on that question both make clear that there is a correlation but not a particularly strong one between muscle size and strength. It's unclear to me why this question is even relevant when there exist both simpler and by definition more accurate ways to measure muscle strength directly that don't require expensive medical scanner time (which is also valuable for diagnosing disease and injury).

Comment: @BryanKrause Direct measurement of muscle strength something isn't possible or advised, e.g. if the tendon is injured. Also, some muscles are difficult to isolate when testing.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Why would you be interested in muscle strength when a tendon is injured? What is the point of assessing the strength of some particular muscle independent of some real physical output (like the amount of weight lifted, the velocity of a thrown ball, etc)?

Comment: @BryanKrause E.g. to find a good balance between muscle strengthening and tendon recovery, in the case of a tendon injury.

Comment: One of the criteria for good SE questions is *"You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face."* - I think your question would be better received if you situate it in the context of injury recovery in which case the measure of interest is probably not 'strength' per se but some measure of health, if that is what you are interested in. It would also be beneficial for you to do some further research on your own to properly scope the question.

Comment: @BryanKrause Thanks, sounds good I edited the question to mention the use case. The measure of interest is strength though, as the muscle itself is healthy, and muscle strength is often regarded as an important factor during tendon recovery.